# foursquare api loading errors

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, foursquare

Hi guys i am getting an error on my project with the foursquare api. I have all of the informaiton that in need and outlined how the api documentation is set up but I am still getting a loading error. here is the code that Ihave and here is the error. if anyone can help me out. the github repository will be listed below

```
var fourSquareMain = 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search';
    var clientID = '5LHFTY54EP5VLMYIIVZ0OQGMNZQEM2FUKDPFFA2OJHMO0AVI';
    var clientSecret = '2TN3GQBAX4U2GPHGMCUZWS35Y2E5E2Y4NG0YWGVGNMXEPHAW';
    var fourSquareVersion = '20160908';
    var fourSquareLL = '&ll=' + pointItem.lat() + ',' + pointItem.lng();
    var fourSquareQuery = '&query=' + pointItem.name;

    var venue_id = pointItem.formattedName();
    var url = fourSquareMain + '/' + venue_id;

    var fullFourSquareQuery = fourSquareMain + clientID + clientSecret + fourSquareVersion + fourSquareLL + fourSquareQuery;
    var finalFSQuery = fullFourSquareQuery.replace(/ /g, '-');

    console.log(finalFSQuery);

    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {
        client_id: "5LHFTY54EP5VLMYIIVZ0OQGMNZQEM2FUKDPFFA2OJHMO0AVI",
        client_secret: "2TN3GQBAX4U2GPHGMCUZWS35Y2E5E2Y4NG0YWGVGNMXEPHAW",
        v: fourSquareVersion,
        async: true
      }
    });
```

here is the error

[this is the error that i am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svgiR.jpg)

github repostory: https://github.com/omar-jandali/udacity-map

Comment: The valid URL for the endpoint is https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search (all other parameters should be passed as GET-parameters as shown [here](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search). Also you can test your URLs with [this tool](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore#req=venues/search%3Fll%3D30.045429,-118.236258%26query%3DPie-Hole).

Comment: You've got a slash after `search`. Should it be a question mark?